# How to access ExtensionBar's DOM from GlobalPage, in Safari Extenision?

Tags: javascript, dom, safari, safari-extension

I'm implementing a Safari Extension, I want to update ExtensionBar's DOM from GlobalPage. How to access ExtensionBar's DOM content from GlobalPage to update it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `safari.extension.bars` contains all the extension bars belonging to your extension. Note that each bar you have defined will have one instance for each open window, and all of them will be included in `safari.extension.bars`.

To access the window object of, e.g., the first extension bar from the global page, use:

```
safari.extension.bars[0].contentWindow
```

and to access the document in it:

```
safari.extension.bars[0].contentWindow.document
```